# Space 4 divs evenly inside a div to fill vertical space

Tags: html, css, position

I am trying to create a parent Div, with 4 children Divs within the parent, all to fill the available space which will automatically adjust on different screen sizes no matter how much text is added. So far, I have been able to code the divs to fill horizontally but not vertically.

I have so far tried variants of Position, Flex, Width and Height to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated. You can gauge what I am trying to accomplish from the image added.

This may seem fairly straightforward although I work mostly with backend development and still learning CCS.

[image]

```
    <div class="d-flex col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
   <div class="boxshadow" style="background-color: #fff; border-radius: 20px; margin: 10px; width: 100%; height: 350px; padding: 40px;">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div class="boxshadow" style="display: flex; flex-flow: column; height: 100%; padding: 20px; margin: 5px;">
                    <h1>12</h1>
                        </div>  
                            </div>
                                                
                                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                                    <div class="boxshadow" style="display: flex; flex-flow: column; height: 100%; padding: 20px; margin: 5px;">
                                                        <h1>22</h1>
                                                    </div>  
                                                </div>
                                                
                                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                                    <div class="boxshadow" style="display: flex; flex-flow: column; height: 100%; padding: 20px; margin: 5px;">
                                                        <h1>36</h1>
                                                    </div>  
                                                </div>
                                                
                                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                                    <div class="boxshadow" style="display: flex; flex-flow: column; height: 100%; padding: 20px; margin: 5px;">
                                                        <h1>47</h1>
                                                    </div>  
                                                </div>
                                            </div>  
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

Aiming to do this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite see what your row and column classes, but a property that might help you here is `flex-wrap`.

When you add `flex-wrap: wrap` to the parent `<div>`, or container, it defines whether the flex items are forced in a single line or can be flowed into multiple lines. Then when the items within the container exeed the `width` property you set, they should wrap. So have a play around with the width of the `child` divs and  the `parent` div

So something similar using your predefined  is in this snippet.

```html
<div class="d-flex col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <div class="boxshadow" style="background-color: #fff; border-radius: 20px; margin: 10px; width: 100%; height: 350px; padding: 40px;">
    <!-- Here is your parent container -->
        <div 
          style="box-shadow: rgba(149, 157, 165, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
                display:flex; 
                width: 120px; 
                flex-wrap: wrap; 
                padding: 20px;"
         >
         
          <div style="box-shadow: rgba(149, 157, 165, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px; display: flex; width: 50px; margin: 5px">
            <h1>12</h1>
          </div>
          
          <div style="box-shadow: rgba(149, 157, 165, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px; display: flex; width: 50px; margin: 5px">
            <h1>22</h1>
          </div>
          
          <div style="box-shadow: rgba(149, 157, 165, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px; display: flex; width: 50px; margin: 5px">
            <h1>36</h1>
          </div>
          
          <div style="box-shadow: rgba(149, 157, 165, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px; display: flex; width: 50px; margin: 5px">
            <h1>47</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
       
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this accomplish the desired effect? There are comments in the css to explain it but essentially it is all done with flexboxes

```css
body, body *{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
}

.d-flex{
  /*
    assumed to be a flex container 
    given existing class name in html.
  */
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  background:rgb(240, 248, 255);
  /*
    make the parent fill the page
  */
  margin:0;
  padding:2rem 1rem;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
}



.d-flex > .boxshadow{
  /* 
    set the 1st child to fill parent
  */
  flex:1;
  background:transparent;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow:0 1rem 1rem rgba(176, 196, 222, 0.75);
}


.d-flex-con{
  /*
    The main container for the 4 divs
  */
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  /*
    Set the container as the flex-container
    that wraps the children.
    
    Change row to column if the numbers are
    to stack vertically etc
  */
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}


.d-flex-item{
  /*
    An individual div element - also set 
    as a flex-container in it's own right
    to aid layout within itself.
    
    Tried to make it look like the picture.
  */
  box-shadow:0 5px 0.5rem rgba(176, 196, 222, 0.75);
  flex:1 1 45%;
  display:flex;
  margin:0.25rem 0.5rem;
  height:50%;
}


.d-flex-item > .boxshadow{
  /* 
    ensure children of the div 
    fill the available space
  */
  flex:1;
  margin:1rem;
}


.d-flex-item > .boxshadow > h1{
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
  <div class="boxshadow">
    <div class="row d-flex-con">
    
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 d-flex-item">
        <div class="boxshadow">
          <h1>12</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 d-flex-item">
        <div class="boxshadow">
          <h1>22</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 d-flex-item">
        <div class="boxshadow">
          <h1>36</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 d-flex-item">
        <div class="boxshadow">
          <h1>47</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```